# Scraping an unordered list row per row with Cheerio in Apify

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, cheerio, apify

I try to scrape the following unordered list:

```
<ul>
 <li class="menu-item">
  <h2 class="menu-item-title">Title</h2>
  <p class="menu-item-description">Description</p>
  <span class="menu-item-price">Price</span>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item">
  <h2 class="menu-item-title">Title</h2>
  <p class="menu-item-description">Description</p>
  <span class="menu-item-price">Price</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And my goal is to scrape the list row per row and get it exactly as is as an HTML table in Apify using the Cheerio scraper and the following code:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { $, request, log } = context;
    log.info(`URL: ${request.url}`);

    var result = [];
    var title = [];
    var description = [];
    var price = [];
    $('li.menu-item h2.menu-item-title').each(function(i, el) {
        title[i] = $(this).text().trim();
    });
    $('li.menu-item p.menu-item-description').each(function(i, el) {
        description[i] = $(this).text().trim();
    });
    $('li.menu-item span.menu-item-price').each(function(i, el) {
        price[i] = $(this).text().trim();
    });

    const numTitles = title.length;
    for (var j=0; j<numTitles; j++) {
        let obj = {
            title: title[j],
            description: description[j],
            price: price[j]
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }
    console.log('result', result);
    return {
        result
    }
}
```

However, the HTML table only shows one super long row instead of one line per row.

from console.log()

```
2019-12-05T19:22:14.028Z   { title: 'Rucola Parmigiano Salad',
2019-12-05T19:22:14.029Z     description: 'Rocket salad with parmesan flakes.',
2019-12-05T19:22:14.030Z     price: '€9.00' },
```

Below is the resulting HTML table:

https://api.apify.com/v2/datasets/qs66oMZsxP2RYodhn/items?format=html&clean=1

How can I fix this to get one ul-line per row?

Comment: I have answered the question but now I think about something else.. How do you use the result of the `pageFunction()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just iterate over each `li` element and push a row-object directly to the `result` array?

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { $, request, log } = context;
    log.info(`URL: ${request.url}`);

    var result = [];
    $('li.menu-item').each(function(i, el) {
        const $this = $(this);
        result.push({
            title: $this.find('h2.menu-item-title').first().text().trim(),
            description: $this.find('p.menu-item-description').first().text().trim(),
            price: $this.find('span.menu-item-price').first().text().trim()
        });
    });

    console.log('result', result);
    return {
        result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are returning one big object called `result`. You can also return an array. If you do that it will push multiple items to the dataset which is exactly what you want.

So instead of

```
return { result };
```

Just

```
return result;
```